# Automation Studio create activities via REST API

Tags: rest-api, automationstudio, activities

I need to create and save an activities with REST API in Automation Studio.
How can I do it?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use SOAP to interact with Automation Studio.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm

([Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm))